# SQLAlchemy batch insert with database functions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to use database functions when inserting multiple values into a table using SQLAlchemy?

If I insert a single row, the following code works fine:

```
conn.execute(
    example_table.insert().values(
        id=17,
        example_field=db.func.concat("foo", "bar")
    )
)
```

The field `example_field` contains the string `foobar`. However, trying to insert multiple rows this way produces unexpected results:

```
conn.execute(example_table.insert(), [{
    "id": 17,
    "example_field": db.func.concat("foo", "bar")
}, {
    "id": 18,
    "example_field": db.func.concat("bar", "baz")
}])
```

The field `example_field` is filled with the string `concat(:concat_1, :concat_2)`.

What is the proper way to insert multiple rows into a table with functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in ["Inserts, Updates and Deletes"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#inserts-updates-and-deletes):

> However, if we wish to use explicitly targeted named parameters with composed expressions, we need to use the [`bindparam()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam) construct.

Create the insert statement with the function call, but with [`bindparam()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam) constructs as arguments:

```
stmt = example_table.insert().\
    values(example_field=func.concat(bindparam('a'), bindparam('b')))

conn.execute(stmt, [
    {"id": 17, "a": "foo", "b": "bar"},
    {"id": 18, "a": "bar", "b": "baz"}])
```

The `concat(:concat_1, :concat_2)` strings are (probably) the result of your DB-API driver converting the function expression objects to strings implicitly:

```
In [5]: str(func.concat("foo", "bar"))
Out[5]: 'concat(:concat_1, :concat_2)'
```

As a comparison [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/) errors out, because it doesn't know what to do with them.